# wpa_supplicant has no interfaces (pydbus)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, dbus, wpa-supplicant

This is a simple code I have that I wrote using the documentation of wpa_supplicant's D-Bus API.

```
from pydbus import SystemBus

bus = SystemBus()
proxy = bus.get('fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1','/fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1')

print(proxy.Interfaces)
```

As per the documentation, it should return the following:

> An array with paths to D-Bus objects representing controlled interfaces each.

However, it returns an empty array, while I would expect to see a path to my wlan0 interface.

I feel like I am missing a previous step but I am completely lost on what it is.

*A few more things that might be useful:*

1. Running `wpa_cli interface_list` returns nothing.
2. Running `ls /var/run/wpa_supplicant/` returns `p2p-dev-wlan0  wlan0`
3. I am not sure how relevant this is, but I am running this on a Raspberry Pi Zero W.

EDIT:
It seems like wpa_supplicant has no clue about what a wlan0 is.

I switched to the `dbus-python` package to see if it was any different and received the following error when trying to get the `wlan0` interface.

```
import dbus

bus = dbus.SystemBus()
wpas_obj = bus.get_object('fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1','/fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1')

wpas = dbus.Interface(wpas_obj, 'fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1')
path = wpas.GetInterface('wlan0')
```

Error: `wpa_supplicant knows nothing about this interface`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After weeks of pain, I am answering myself for the sake of completion and with the hope that someday this is useful to somebody else.

The error was in the way that the `wpa_supplicant` service was creating the interfaces. All it was missing was the `-u` flag.

Taken from the wpa_supplicant manual:

```
-u     Enable DBus control interface. If enabled, interface definitions may be omitted. (This is only available if wpa_supplicant was built with the CONFIG_DBUS option.)
```

Once I figured out the error it was a rather easy fix. However, here is further explanation on how to fix this, just in case you are still a bit lost.

Simply edit your service file, it should be something like `wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service`, **not** `wpa_supplicant.service`, that part is important. Then append the `-u` flag on the line that says `ExecStart`.

To edit a service file you can use something similar to

`sudo systemctl edit nameofyour.service --full`

and follow up with

`sudo systemctl restart nameofyour.service`

You may need to reboot your device after that.